# Signing in removed bookmarks

Tags: google-chrome, login, bookmarks

I haven't used Chrome's sign-in option yet, but my friend just came over and signed in on my computer to gain access to some bookmarks he wanted to show me.

We signed him out, deleted his account and now we can't find any of them.  I use my bookmarks as a private pin board, but can't find the bookmark file or backup file anywhere.

I'm on Mac OSx and am using Chrome 24.

**EDIT**

We tried restarting Chrome, and it didn't help...

Comment: You can't find his or your bookmarks?

Comment: No. I tried /Users/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome, but there was no /Default folder.